# Disable autoscroll in ListBox in mfc application

Tags: mfc, listbox, scrollbar

So, in my MFC application there is a Listbox, where sometimes calls method AddString. In properties of Listbox - Scroll is true, and it works fine. And when added strings are many, scrollbar appears, but slider is always below. When I raise it to look previous strings, it goes down after calling Addstring method.

How can I bring slider don't movie after calling Addstring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`CListBox::AddString` adds the string to the *end of the list* if `LBS_SORT` is not given. But there is no chance of slider moving down as it **cannot** cause a selection change. Make sure you are not calling `SetCurSel`, `SetTopIndex` or `SelectString` after `AddString`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly just call `SetCurSel(0);` after the `AddString`.